# WordPress / Bootstrap mobile site issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have an issue on a particular website - [http://stonecrestre.com](http://stonecrestre.com/) - that I've been scratching my head for days now trying to solve.

There's a horizontal scroll on the front page that I can't seem to get rid of. I've went through all the possible divs and classes that might be causing it but no margins or paddings of 0 seem to fix it.*

**^ This issue has been fixed thanks to help from user: JBA**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when using `<div class="row">` : it adds negative margin on its left and on its right. This is causing your issue... Maybe put this row into a col-md-12 to end up with 0 lateral shift...

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much! With your suggestion I was able to tweak the 'full-page-width' template to eliminate that pesky horizontal scroll.

Now to just figure out why the menu keeps disappearing.